# Can you just use vim scripts and plugins with emacs' evil mode? what are evil mode's limitations?

Tags: vim, emacs, vim-plugin

What the title says.
Thinking about starting to use emacs, have some experience in vim now and a decent setup with vim plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `evil` is still based around Emacs Lisp.  There is no attempt to implement a `vimscript` interpreter, and `evil` doesn't turn Emacs into vim -- it's still Emacs... just an Emacs with lots of vim features.

Comment: can't I just port the code of the vimscript interpreter in vim to elisp or much simpler, simply yank all the code for it, compile it and run it as a binary from within emacs? In my naivety I'd assume that would be the simplest approach for implementing what evil mode wants to do

Comment: You could try "just" porting the vimscript interpreter to elisp.  I've never heard of anyone attempting that, and it would probably be a great deal of work and very slow by comparison.  The vimscript interpreter in Vim is written in C, so the performance difference between that and a version written in elisp would be vast.

Comment: To your latter thought, if you were somehow running the actual vimscript interpreter inside Emacs, what would it be interfacing with?  Vim and Emacs don't share internal data structures and APIs.  There would be no way for the 'Vim bits' to interact with any of Emacs unless you implemented that.

Comment: If you wanted to implement a vimscript interpreter in elisp, you could, and supporting stuff like rtp would make it easy to port .vim directories—but at that point you’ve more or less implemented vim in elisp without the default keybindings.